# How can I install the service using installutil.exe

Tags: c#, windows-services

How can I install the web service using installutil.exe?

I get a Windows Service start failure error every time I start.

Comment: providing the error would help

Comment: This question can be closed as missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your service is probably throwing an exception on startup. Check the windows event log

Answer (score 1):

I think installutil.exe is use to install the windowservice 
Ex:
To Install the windowservice

C:>installutil Path(windowservice.exe)

To Uninstall the windowservice

C:>installutil /u Path(windowservice.exe)